# Mongoose point-free style functions are not been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I encounter a problem while using mongoose with nodejs.

I want process documents with some higher-order function in point-free style after query a collection:

```
// the 1st higher-order function:
const macdCalculator = strategy => (data) => {
  console.log('==================')
  console.log('process data with strategy');

  return strategy.process(data);
};

// the 2nd higher-order function:
const balanceCalculator = strategy => (data) => {
  console.log('==================')
  console.log('process data with strategy');

  return strategy.anotherProcess(data);
};

// this just a function
const markOperations = (data) => {
  console.log('==================')
  console.log('start mark operation');

  return someProcess(data);
};

// variables that hold the produced function:
let calculateMacd;
let calculateBalance;

// start query, main program
MyCollection.findById(testId)
  .populate('target')
  .populate('strategy')
  .then(({ target, strategy }) => {
    calculateMacd = macdCalculator(strategy);   // <- produce a funciton
    calculateBalance = balanceCalculator(strategy);   // <- produce another function
    return aggregateData(testId, target.dataSet, strategy.interval);  // <- aggregate some data
  })
  .then(calculateMacd)  //  <- this function seems not been called, the data just passed through!
  .then(markOperations)  //  <- this function has been called, but not working due to the previous step is failed.
  .then(calculateBalance)  //  <- this function also not been called, the data just passed through!
  .then(result => MyOtherCollection.insertMany(result))  // wrong result I got
  .then(() => process.send('test done'))
```

And I found that, if I don't use the point-free style, those function will be called correctly:

```
.then(data => calculateMacd(data))   // this is working
.then(data => calculateBalance(data))   // this is working too
```

I'm not that familiar with mongoose, so why is this happening? And the "markOperations" functions, why this point-free style working?

Is there anything I missed?

I'm very confused, please help. Thanks.